# Restart Gunicorn after specific request completes

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I want to kill a gunicorn worker after each request to a specific endpoint:

1. User sends `GET /endpoint`
2. A particular Gunicorn worker process X accepts the request and responds with `200 OK`, using Flask underneath.
3. X gets killed, replaced by a new Gunicorn worker process Y automatically.

I could only find a way to restart after *any* request (use Gunicorn's  `max_requests` settings), but that's not what I want. **Basically, I need `max_requests=1` but only applied to one specific endpoint, not all endpoints.**

Answer (score 0):

I asked exactly the same question and came to the following solution using the `gunicorn.conf.py` [file](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=gunicorn%20conf#config):

```
import os
import signal


reload_me_daddy = {
    "/full/uri/to_endpoint?even_with=query_params",
}


def post_request(worker, req, environ, resp):
    if req.uri in reload_me_daddy:
        os.kill(worker.pid, signal.SIGHUP)
```

#### Explanation

Using `post_request` [hook](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#post-request), that's

> "Called after a worker processes the request"

I am able to reload worker by sending to him HUP signal (from 'Signal Handling' [docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/signals.html?highlight=signal%20handling#master-process)):

> `HUP`: Reload the configuration, start the new worker processes with a new configuration and gracefully shutdown older workers...

So, yeah, `os.kill(worker.pid, signal.SIGHUP)` in my example is effectively equivalent of

```bash
kill -HUP $WORKER_PID
```

command, that, as I understand, appears to be the most 'graceful' worker reload method anyway.

To reload only on specific endpoint in my example I used full uri from request object, but following attributes of request object are also available (so you can use them to separate requests to your specific endpoint):

- `req.method` - like 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT' etc.
- `req.path` - same as uri, but without query string (using uri in my example here I would get following path "/full/uri/to_endpoint")
- `req.body` - well, it's request body (didn't test this one)